# Write a namespaced function for jQuery that operates on parameters and not selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, prototype-programming

I've been tying to start a library of functions in jQuery to use transversally in my code
I thought that a good way of doing this would be to build a jQuery namespace and add my
methods under that (and provide the namespace for all who would like to contribute).
This is what I came up with:

```
(function( $ )
{
    $.extend
    ({
        mynamespace:
        {
            myfunction: function(a, b)
            {
                if (!Math.prototype.newmethod)
                {
                    Math.prototype.newmethod = function(c, d)
                    {
                        // newmethod code
                    }
                }
                // myfunction code (uses Math.newmethod)
            }
        }
    })
})(jQuery);
```

Now this worked fine in the small test file where I originally called it (the code did what I wanted it to) but after execution I got the following error:

> DOM Exception:
>   **INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR (5)**

I ignored it, not being sure where it was coming from nor how to fix it (the few references I found on the web associated the problem with IE9 which I was not using) but when I used my new code site-wide everything started breaking with error messages such as

> **Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function**

and

> **Uncaught TypeError: Object function (c, d) { // newmethod code }**

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong are welcome

P.S.
The way I call the code described above is:

```
var temp = $.mynamespace.myfunction(a, b);
```

Comment: Run your code under a debugger and tell it to pause on exceptions. That should help you find out where the problems are comming from.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you'd want to use a jQuery namespace? You could just as easily provide your own which might make things easier. I know that opinions differ, but instead of e.g. extending the Math object, I'd probably create e.g. a `Utilities` name space with a `math` object which again could hold all math related methods. — Just a thought.

Comment: re: polarblau. That's a good suggestion (as you hint, it is a design choice though). At this point, I'm just hung up on the knowledge of the matter. I can do a work-around, like you suggest, but now that I have been given this task, I would like to learn something new in the process. In any case, I don't think that the Math prototyping is the problem. Rather the Math prototyping in conjunction with the jQuery extending. If I had to guess, I would say that my problem has something to do with my code overriding other code (in the jQuery library) and I want to learn how to avoid this.

Comment: re: missingno. I tried that before. It's some function in jQuery. I'll have to download the readable jQuery and debug it properly. Thanks. Do you see any obvious syntax issues with what I have done though?

Comment: Hi. `Math` is not a function and thus has no prototype property. `Math.prototype; //null`. It's generally bad habit to change the prototype of javascript objects, even more if you are the only using it in your own function.

Comment: re Didier: Is that what I am doing in the code? I thought that I was just adding functionality to the object but if by calling its prototype I am fundamentally changing the object itself and overwriting its inherent methods, that may be the issue. I thought that the line where I write "(!Math.prototype.newmethod)" was a sufficient precaution to avoid corrupting the original object.

Comment: @ErezSemaria I would seriously recommend reading JavaScript Patterns: http://www.amazon.com/JavaScript-Patterns-Stoyan-Stefanov/dp/0596806752